# filling ul li with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, fill

I have problem with ul li fill with

```
<ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ul>
```

I need to put in all **li**  with **javascript**

but please without this example :

```
$("ul").html("<li><img src='something' /></li>");
```

Because i need this ul li before javascript load.

I want after javascript to look like :

```
<ul>
    <li><img src='something' /></li>
    <li><img src='something' /></li>
    <li><img src='something' /></li>
    <li><img src='something' /></li>
</ul>
```

My question is : How to fill all ul li with images.

And javascript work with for loop. Because maybe i have this variant :

```
<ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ul>
```

4 li and only 2 image, and to look like this :

```
<ul>
    <li><img src='something' /></li>
    <li><img src='something' /></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I hope i explain this. Thanks anyway

My php code :

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('connect.php');

$path = "../uploads/";
$i = -1;
foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key => $name) {
    $i++;
    $image_info = getimagesize($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]);
    $image_width = $image_info[0];
    $image_height = $image_info[1];

    if($image_width > $image_height) {
        $height = $image_height;
        $width = $height;
    } else if($image_width < $image_height) {
        $width = $image_width;
        $height = $width;
    } else {
        $width = $image_width;
        $height = $image_height;
    }

    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]);

    imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, ($image_width/2)-($width/2), ($image_height/2)-($height/2), $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($canvas, $path.'cropped_'.$name, 100);


    echo 
    "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var _img = document.createElement('img');
            _img.src = 'uploads/".$name."';

            $('.image-upload ul li:nth(".$i.")').append(_img);
        </script>
    ";
}

?>
```

Before : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnfZm.png

After
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve1CC.png

Comment: Simply use $("li").append("<li><img src='something' /></li>");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var _ul=document.getElementByTagName('ul');
var _list=_ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i=0;i<=_list.length;i++)
  {
    var _img=document.createElement('img');
    _img.src="something";
    _img.id="foo"+i;
    _list[i].appendChild(_img);

  }
```

Comment: thanks, i have one more problem, because this code is part of php file, and I echo script. When echo script. My ul li was removed and <script></script> showed

Comment: I found mistake, how i can load script from response(xhr) ?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use loops to fill all the `li` tags with images. Use,

```
$("li").append("<img src='something' />");
```

If you want to add images for first 2 `li` tags, Use like this

```
$("li:lt(2)").append("<img src='something' />");
```

Comment: no need for additional <li> in append. it's not what OP wants. :)

Comment: @Holybreath Thank you for pointing it. I just copied the html from question. didnt notices the tags inside it.

Comment: @Holybreath thanks for the answer, but, I nned loop, I work all this for upload image and preview them before "upload"(only on browse them) and with xhr, I call php file with foreach loop. In foreach loop there is javascript to show image in already existing ul li, and when there is 3 image, to edit only 3 ul li(the rest of ul li to be visible and not changed) do you understand me now?